# SonarQube issue:Remove duplicate in this character class error

Tags: javascript, regex, sonarqube

I have implemented this regex in my code:

```
/[\D\s]/g
```

but SonarQube gives this code-smell issue:

> Remove duplicate in this character class error

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

The message *"Remove duplicate in this character class error"* makes sense, because `\s` is a subset of `\D`. In other words, when you allow for any non-digit, you implicitly allow for a white space character too, and so adding `\s` as an "extra" possibility is not changing anything, because that was already a possibility with just `\D`.

This suggests that you should change `[\D\s]` to just `\D`, as that will match exactly the same characters.